# how to change background color of text bottom up

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a text color change either bottom up or up to bottom on hover.

```css
.box {
    width: 200px; height: 100px;
    background-size: 100% 200%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, red 50%, green 50%);
    -webkit-transition: background-position 1s;
    -moz-transition: background-position 1s;
    transition: background-position 1s;
}

.box:hover {
    background-position: 0 -100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Text</div>
```

the above code makes the box change color instead the text. What can I do to make the text color instead of the box.

Comment: simply add this `-webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;`

Comment: @taki yes that looks good except mine is on hover

Comment: @hmrous on hover or on click it's the same ;) and the one provided by taki is not the only one ... there is more questions/answer dealing with the same

Comment: @TemaniAfif This question is better than the dupe I believe, has better answers, what do you think?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I don't consider the other question as a dup because it's too broad (if it was the case I would already close this one) but with my comment I meant that having a click or hover is not a reason to say that the question is not the same and am pretty sure there is other questions dealing with the same effect as I answered them before. It was hard to find them and since we got answers and upvotes here, there is no more need.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Gotcha... Thanks for the clarification. `:D`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gotta use [Background Clip](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip):

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, red 50%, green 50%);
  -webkit-transition: background-position 3s;
  -moz-transition: background-position 3s;
  transition: background-position 3s;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 50pt;
}

.box:hover {
  background-position: 0 -100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Text</div>
```

**Note:** I have increased the font size and time to 3 seconds to see the effect well.

Comment: in addition, do you know any library that I can use to do the same effect when the page is scrolled

Comment: You can very well use jQuery but depends on the use case.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the effect using an overlay (the `before` pseudo element) with the background, and [`mix-blend-mode: screen`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode):

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 5em;
  background: white;
}

.box::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: 100% 200%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, red 50%, green 50%);
  transition: background-position 1s;
  content: '';
  pointer-events: none;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}

.box:hover::before {
  background-position: 0 -100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Text</div>
```